# How to replace with Vim using regex

Tags: regex, vim, macvim

I am trying to beatify my HAML code, so I need to change every `:word => text` to `word: text`.

**Some more examples:**

1. `:align => text` should be `align: text`
2. `:style => 'display: block;font-family: Arial'` should be `style:
   'display: block;font-family: Arial'`

I tried to do that with Vim regex, and here what I used for replacement:

`:%s /:\w*\s=>/\1:\w/g`

But unfortunately that doesn't do what I described above.

Comment: Can you post a few more specific examples of input and the expected output replacements? It is unclear where that `'` goes from your example `:word => '` because it is not addressed in your regex attempt

Comment: It would help if you put the examples into context of their lines, rather than just the pattern to match & replace.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
:%s/:\(\w\+\)\s*=>\(\s*\)/\1:\2/g
```

Or, with very-magic mode to use fewer backslashes:

```
:%s/\v:(\w+)\s*\=\>(\s*)/\1:\2/g
```

The `\2` preserves the whitespace to the right of the `=>` in a somewhat half-hearted attempt to keep things lined up after the change.

Comment: Working but there is an extra space after the colon, i.e. `style: (double spaces) text`.

Comment: Also it doesn't work on the second string if the line is like this `{:align => 'center', :style => 'padding: 27px 0;'}`. It just replace the first `:align =>` and leave the `:style =>` as is.

Comment: If you have multiple key=>value pairs on a line, then you need the `/g` on the end of the substitute command.  Added.

Comment: Thanks for it, it works perfectly, and I learned some new things from it.